# Select part of multidimensional Matrix by boolean array

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, julia

I want to select a part of an multidimensional Array by an other matrix with boolean entries.

So if the cell is "true" i want to have the number in the cell. If it is "false" it should be 0.

Example:

> M = rand(Int64[1:5],3,4,2)
> 3x4x2 Array{Int64,3}:
>
> [:, :, 1] =
>
> 5  5  1  2
>
> 1  2  3  4
>
> 4  2  5  4
>
> [:, :, 2] =
>
> 2  4  1   1
>
> 3  5  3   1
>
> 1  1  4   5
>
> B=
>
> 3x4 Bitarray {2}:
>
> false false false false
>
> false true false false
>
> false false true false

the Result shoud be:

> Mred=
>
> [:,:,1]=
>
> 0 0 0 0
>
> 0 2 0 0
>
> 0 0 5 0
>
> [:,:,2]=
>
> 0 0 0 0
>
> 0 5 0 0
>
> 0 0 5 0

I tried stuff like:

> Mred=M[B,:]

or

> Mred=M[(B,1),(B,2),2]

and a lot of other things, but something is missing and the dimensions seem to be of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use element-wise multiplication:

```
M.*B
```

Comment: Thank you. If i follow your suggestion: M[1,2].*B i leave out the third dimension of the example.  So your solution is not going to work.

Comment: @Hainmueck But, if you use Felipe's suggest exactly as written (rather than using `M[1,2].*B` as in your comment), it produces exactly the output you requested in your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. I somehow messed up and it only worked the way i wrote it in the comment. Now it did work and i only have to figure out why it doesn't work for four dimension (the original sizes are M:2x2500X3X1000 and B:[2500x3]